# How To Add-Onto For Loop Without Looping From The Beginning?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to get a list to display into my combo box, each time a user inputs a new boat name & a boat license, they both get added to the combobox.

```
for(int i = 0; i < boatList.Count; i++)
    {
        BoatSelector.Items.Add(boatList[i].GetboatName() + " - " + boatList[i].GetboatLicense());
    }
```

Expected Result : Name + License from the users input, should be added onto the combo box.

Actual Result : Name + License get's added, then the for loop, loops back to 0 and re-adds the same name & license, while also adding any newer ones.

Comment: It looks like you just forgot to clear the ComboBox items (i.e., `BoatSelector.Items.Clear();`)?

Comment: Alternatively, you may add _only_ the new items. This can be achieved in a number of ways; one of which would be not to start the loop at 0 but at the first new index instead. However, clearing the items before adding the whole list should work just fine.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I wanted the items stored, rather than cleared, how would I start the loop on a new index?

Comment: Can you please give us more info about "Name + License get's added"? What does it get added to?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## *'make a for loop start from the new index'*

> I didn't want to store new inputs in the beginning of the list, nor do I want to clear the list, I just wanted to find a way to make a for loop start from the new index, rather than displaying the previous index again.

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var last = boatList.Last() // using System.Linq;
var last = boatList[boatList.Count/Count()/Length - 1] // etc. 

BoatSelector.Items.Add(lastItem.GetboatName() + " - " + last.GetboatLicense());
```

## *'on a new index'*

> I wanted the items stored, rather than cleared, how would I start the loop on a new index?

Do you mean at the beginning of the list? If so, you can use `InsertAt`

```
BoatSelector.Items.InsertAt(0,boatList[i].GetboatName() + " - " + boatList[i].GetboatLicense());
```

---

## *'re-adds the same'*

> and re-adds the same name & license, while also adding any newer ones

I think you're adding the items multiple times.

```
for(int i = 0; i < boatList.Count; i++)
{
    BoatSelector.Items.Add(boatList[i].GetboatName() + " - " + boatList[i].GetboatLicense());
}   

(... at another time)


for(int i = 0; i < boatList.Count; i++)
{
    BoatSelector.Items.Add(boatList[i].GetboatName() + " - " + boatList[i].GetboatLicense());
}
```

This means that `BoatSelector.Items` always grows.

You can `Clear()` `Items` or assign a new list:

```
BoatSelector.Items = boatList
          .Select( item => item.GetboatName() + " - " + item.GetboatLicense())
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I didn't want to store new inputs in the beginning of the list, nor do I want to clear the list, I just wanted to find a way to make a for loop start from the new index, rather than displaying the previous index again.